# Plots in R involving two categorical variables

Tags: r, data-visualization, heatmap

I have data containing

```
v1<-sample(c( "A", "B","C","D"),100,replace=T)

v2<-sample(c(0,1),100,replace=T)

dta<-data.frame(cbind(v1,v2))
```

Both `v1`, `v2` are factor variables. I want to know what kinds of graphs there exist to explore their relationship. Can I get a heat map, can it be done in R?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the heatmap function on a contingency table and skip the dendrograms (parameters `Colv` and `Rowv`).

```
heatmap(table(v1,v2), Colv=NA, Rowv=NA, scale='none')
```

[image: Heatmap]

Comment: can you please elaborate it , I need to interpret it

Comment: Well, I just used your code to generate v1 and v2. Make yourself familiar with the table function and play with heatmaps parameters: Colv, Rowv and scale.